# Question from Machine Learning Textbook on Number of Models

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

In the James, Witten, et.al Statistical Learning textbook, it says the following:

"Unfortunately, there are a total of $2^p$ models that contain subsets of $p$ variables."

Can someone please explain how the $2^p$ is obtained?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider each variable. For a given subset that variable is either included or it is not included in that subset. There are therefore 2 choices for each variable. There is no dependence so the full number of states is the product of the number of states for each variable: $2^p$

Answer (score 1):

The number of distinct subsets (including the empty set) of a set with $p$ elements is $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom pk = (1+1)^p = 2^p$$
To each subset (of variables) corresponds a model, so there are $2^p$ models.

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector that describes your model: $$ v = \overbrace{
v_1v_2v_3\dots v_p
   }^\text{variables}$$
where $v_i=1$ if the variable $i$ is included into a model, or 0 if it's skipped.

How may combinations of variables you can get? It's $2^p$